# 206 Partial Request - Single-range request with overlapping bytes

Tags: http-headers, httpserver, rfc2616

I am implementing a module that supports 206 partial requests.
After reading RFC rfc2616, i noticed that when receiving a multi-range request, overlapping ranges such as: "a-b, a-d" are not allowed.

My question is:

What happens with single-range request and overlapping bytes?

```
 Request #1:   a-b
 Request #2:   a-d
```

Do I need to ignore bytes a-b in the second request?

OR

Do I need to overwrite the bytes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite the bytes.

Responses does not depend on any previous request semantically because HTTP is a stateless protocol.